# How to deal with expired access_token

Tags: facebook, oauth

The case:

1. We plug-in FB JS and init it with `FB.init()`. This call creates `fbsr_NNNNN` cookie. The cookie has session-limited expiration date (until browser is closed). We call `FB.init()` only once in this example. After that we call the pages that don't contain `FB.init()` invocations so it doesn't have a chance to renew the access_token
2. We perform authentication and make some server-side (PHP FB SDK) call, like `/me`
3. Wait for 30 minutes or something until FB session expires
4. Perform the `/me` request again and see "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

This happens because current php sdk implementation:

```
  public function getSignedRequest() {
    if (!$this->signedRequest) {
      if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) {
        $this->signedRequest = $this->parseSignedRequest(
          $_REQUEST['signed_request']);
      } else if (isset($_COOKIE[$this->getSignedRequestCookieName()])) {
        $this->signedRequest = $this->parseSignedRequest(
          $_COOKIE[$this->getSignedRequestCookieName()]);
      }
    }
    return $this->signedRequest;
  }
```

just takes the `access_token` from cookies as-is and in case of exception it doesn't clear it. So the code has no chance to return into normal workflow without manual cookie removing. Yes, if I delete the cookie - the code starts to work again (as long as there is no saved access_token and library fetches the new actual one).

So what workaround for this issue would you propose? What do you use? Do you think it is a bug?

**UPD**: seems like there is a possible workaround: to extend `Facebook` class and override the method that cleans persistent storages. For details look at discussion to the answer http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/8294559/251311

But I'm personally still sure that FB SDK should handle it without any additional hacks

Comment: I think this post will aid in some solution: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/ Hope it helps you

Comment: Nope, it is about another cases. It states nothing about handling "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." And I don't want to reimplement the OAuth manually, I just want the solution that will work with FB PHP SDK

Comment: There's none. It's the result of combining PHP and JS, where PHP does the work using data provided by JS, but without JS to keep the data active.

Comment: @Tom van der Woerdt: yeah, exactly! `FB.init()` is used just once, to set up the cookie. After that it is not called anymore so it doesn't have a chance to refresh the token...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: I have no experience with Facebook itself, but the OAuth 2 RFC specifies a `refresh_token` - consider implementing it.

Second: Facebook returns an error, right? If that error occurs just unset the cookie. If that doesn't work with your current implementation you're doing something wrong - pretty much every Twitter library I have seen (also uses OAuth, albeit 1.0a) uses its own HTTP wrapper. Rather than giving back an URL to request you simply execute the request yourself.

Third: What if you simply set a timeout on the cookie? I'm rather sure OAuth also gives you an `expires_in` value, simply use it (do take 5 seconds off this value, because of network lag etc).

Comment: `If that error occurs just unset the cookie`, yes, but it should be handled by the client shipped by facebook, shouldn't it? `Third: What if you simply set a timeout on the cookie?` --- the cookie is defined by FB JS, not by my code.

Comment: `OAuth also gives you` --- yes, it does, but I have no access to that information, because it is completely processed by the client

Comment: Ah, the JS/PHP mixup :-) You do have a point though. **Maybe you should consider implementing the OAuth login as well** (rather than FB.init()) - it's very easy to do, especially if you use a library. As far as I know, the JS version keeps the data intact to be able to refresh the token when needed. If the data was gone, it would never know the session was ever created, so it has to keep it, even if it's expired. Simply grab a new token and `setcookie()` it

Comment: actually I do have OAuth login performed by server-side (php) and to be clear JS just calls `FB.init()` without any other logic. And the issue is that even though I don't use any FB OAuth thing from js - it stores the cookie anyway, and php just trusts that cookie is valid :-S I just cannot "grab new access_token" because php sdk looks at the cookie and sees that there is access_token already there - so it uses it :-S

Comment: Then why are you calling `FB.init()` ? Also, I'm fairly sure that the FB PHP SDK can take care of refreshing tokens...

Comment: because it is "general template" ;-) FB PHP SDK cannot refresh tokens - I've pasted the code, that doesn't take care of tokens validity, it just takes them as-is from either request or cookies

Comment: Look at Line 1042: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L1042 - it actually does take care of access token expirations.

Comment: yes, it calls `$this->setAccessToken(null);` but the issue is that `setAccessToken` doesn't take care of any persistent storage: https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php#L293 so it just nulls it within current request. And on next request we see the same issue: php sdk sees it is an access_token in cookie, performs the request, catches the exception, nulls it in current object, ...

Comment: Actually, it also clears persistent storage ( https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php#L82 ). What about writing a simple wrapper that checks for an `accessToken` (on the FB object), and if it's changed to `null` unsets the cookie?

Comment: yeah, it can do the trick, but I'm still sure that php sdk out of the box should do that. Don't you think so? And thanks in investigations! +1

Comment: I definitely agree - every library I have seen (okay, it was Twitter, but same thing happens there) implements that, except for this official one.